# CSS does not take effect unless I resize the window?

Tags: javascript, css

## Problem

Strange issue: Some CSS appears correctly in Chrome's developer tools but does not actually take effect until I resize the browser window. Just expanding the window by a pixel or two is enough. But the window needs to be resized to force the browser to update this particular detail.

### More detail

Attached is a screenshot of the issue. A corner maintains a 10px radius even though the CSS says it should be 0px.

*What happened just before this screenshot*: When the user clicks a `<tr>` (dark blue row in image) a hidden row beneath it is exposed (white). This action also triggers the CSS update through a `classList.toggle`, and the update is correctly shown in the developer tools. But it does not take effect, as you can see.

[image]

I have made a simplified version of the code as a snippet. But in this example, the CSS *does* takes effect, so there is no issue with the code.

So my question is if anyone else has experienced anything like this in their own work? And can point to what the issue may be? Cheers.

```js
$('tr.clickable').on('click', (e) => {
$(e.currentTarget).toggleClass('open')
e.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('shown')
})
```

```css
body {background-color: #dadbd6}

table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed}

tr {color: #fff;
   filter: 
   drop-shadow(0px 0.1em 0.1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 40%)) /* main shadow */ 
   drop-shadow(0px 1px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 20%))
   drop-shadow(0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 30%))}

tr.open {background-color: #bb0000}
tr.childrow:not(.shown) {display: none}

td {padding: 20px;}
tr:not(.open) {background-color: #000}

tr td:nth-child(1) {width: 5%; border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px}  
tr td:nth-child(2) {width: 5%}  
tr td:nth-child(3) {width: 40%}  
tr td:nth-child(4) {width: 15%}  
tr td:nth-child(5) {width: 10%}
tr td:nth-child(6) {width: 10%}
tr td:nth-child(7) {width: 10%} 
tr td:nth-child(8) {width: 5%} 

tr:not(.open) td:nth-child(8) {border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0} 
tr.open td:nth-child(8) {border-radius: 0 10px 0 0}
tr.open td:nth-child(1) {border-radius: 10px 0 0 0}
tr.childrow td {border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class='clickable'>
<td>A</td>
<td>B</td>
<td>C</td>
<td>D</td>
<td>E</td>
<td>F</td>
<td>G</td>
<td>H</td>
</tr>
<tr class='childrow'><td colspan="8">I am no longer hidden</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: background-color isn't inherited so what actually has that dark gray color and the rounded corners?  Please show us more of the styling of the table and tr.

Comment: @AHaworth The rounded corner code can be seen in the snippet. It's on the `<tr>`. I have now also added the drop-shadow to the snippet, so it's more like the code seen in the screenshot.

Comment: So it's tr we need to look at? Nothing to do with the td? Is that right?

Comment: @AHaworth I wish I could tell you. The shadow is on the `<tr>`, and the rounded corners are on the `<td>` as you cannot round corners on a `<tr>`. But as to what is causing the issue, I have no idea. This is the first time I have encountered a situation, where the CSS updates correctly following an action, but what is rendered on the screen does not fully reflect this unless something else (e.g. a window resize) forces the browser to refresh the rendering.

Comment: I think you’ll have to provide a version that shows the problem.

Comment: @AHaworth Almost impossible as there are 2,000+ lines of JS and CSS. And I cannot identify the culprit, as the correct CSS actually kicks through in the browser, as you can see. It's just not rendered. So I assume it is some fringe case, and I hope someone else has experienced something similar.

Answer (score 0):

It's a hack, but I found a solution: If I also set the `background-color` on the `<td>` element, this will make the browser re-render and also set the corner radius to 0, as desired.

It makes no difference to the color, as I just set the color on the `<td>` to the same as the `<tr>` parent.

So this code left the corner rounded:

```
tr.opentr td.list-ticker {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;}
```

But this made the 0px radius on the bottom-left take effect:

```
 tr.opentr td.list-ticker {
     border-top-left-radius: 10px;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
     background-color: #1c4966;}
```

Very strange, but it does the job.